# Map between Eclipse Compiler Errors and QuickFix Suggestions

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors

I want to create a map between Java compiler errors detected by Eclipse (as key) and the Eclipse Quick fix suggestions (as values).

I found the below page contains available Eclipse Quick Fix suggestions.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-java-editor-quickfix.htm

However, I could not find a page shows a map between Eclipse compiler errors and their quick fix suggestions. Please let me know where I can find these relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you reference says `Here's a selection of available quick fixes` - it is not a complete list and gets bigger with each release.

The list of quick fixes available depends on how many plugins you have installed in Eclipse that provide quick fixes using the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.quickFixProcessors` extension point.

The primary quick fix processor for Java is `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.correction.QuickFixProcessor`. You can look at the source of that to see the errors that are processed (about 224 in Eclipse Kepler).